# PHP Fatal Error on specific PHP installation - Call to undefined method DOMText::getElementsByTagName()

Tags: php, dom

I'm having a problem with code working on one PHP install and not working on the other. Maybe one install is more forgiving when it comes to the error.

When I upload to production I receive the following error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DOMText::getElementsByTagName() in ...
```

The line causing the error is:

```
$tds = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td');
```

I have a feeling the issue is related to calling the `getElementsByTagName` method from within `DOMText::` instead of `DOMDocument::` ([the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) seem to make this obvious) but out of my lack of understanding of what I've done wrong, I am not sure how to address the issue.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

// The HTML
$table_html = '<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>AAA</td>
            <td>BBB</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>';


// Create DOM Document
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$document->formatOutput = true;
@$document->loadHTML($table_html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);

// Change TD's to TH's in THEAD's
$theads = $document->getElementsByTagName('thead')->item(0);
if ($theads) {

    foreach($theads->childNodes AS $tr) {

        $tds = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td'); // <---- This is where the error occurs
        if ($tds->length > 0) {

            $i = $tds->length - 1;
            while($i > -1) {
                $td = $tds->item($i); // td
                $text = $td->nodeValue; // text node
                $th = $document->createElement('th', $text); // th element with td node value
                $td->parentNode->replaceChild($th, $td); // replace
                $i--;
            }

        }

    }
}

// Output
echo $document->saveHTML();
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domtext.php there no method getElementsByTagName()

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say `childNodes` contains the whitespace textnodes between `<thead>` and `<tr>`. You might have to use `foreach($theads->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr)` instead (or just use XPath which is heaps easier)

Comment: @Phil That did it! Thank you!! Please add it as an answer so I can give you the credit :)

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo Yes I get that. As you can see from my code I didn't explicitly use DOMText which caused my confusion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is, `childNodes` includes the whitespace text nodes between each tag.

To get the `<tr>` tags in `$theads`, use `getElementsByTagName`, eg

```
foreach ($theads->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr) {
    // ...
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you're after all the `<td>` elements in the first `<thead>`, try XPath

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$tds = $xpath->query('//thead[1]/tr/td'); // xpath indexes are 1-based
```